# Function get ivoked on every page in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, fetch

I've got a simple React App using React-Router. Every Component in a Router is an individual *.jsx file.

Also I've got a fetch.js - file where are fetch-functions to deal with a server side using JWTs.

So there is a UserPage.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { getDataByToken, sendData } from '../fetch'
import Navbar from '../Components/UI/Navbar/Navbar'
import classes from './UserInfo.module.css'
import NewInput from '../Components/UI/NewInput/NewInput'


getDataByToken("http://127.0.0.1:5000/@me").then(result => {
      if (result.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem('nick', result.data[1])
        localStorage.setItem('email', result.data[3])
      }
    }) 

const UserInfo = () => {...}
...
export default UserInfo
```

`getDataByToken` does a GET-request to take a info from server to put it into the page. If server responses with 400-code, this function calls an other function to refresh the JWTs and if this refresh-func gets a 400-code, it redirects user in the login page.

There is a problem: this `getDataByToken` calls on EVERY PAGE. On /login, on /, on 'register.

Although i want this function to be called only on page, which UserInfo is pinned at.

Also firstly I tried to put `getDataByToken` in UserInfo, but every time when any component got changed, this function invoked and sent a request to server. (I have a textarea there, so requests were sent every time i inputed a letter into it)

Thank you!

Comment: This is what `useEffect` is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really call it like that, instead wherever you need to call `getDataByToken` you insert it inside a `useEffect`'s Effect callback function and pass it a second argument of empty array `[]` - meaning empty dependency list meaning it'll run only when Component mounts (on the first initial render and never again on the following re-renders).

```
// import useEffect
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { getDataByToken, sendData } from '../fetch'
import Navbar from '../Components/UI/Navbar/Navbar'
import classes from './UserInfo.module.css'
import NewInput from '../Components/UI/NewInput/NewInput'


// getDataByToken("http://127.0.0.1:5000/@me").then(result => {
//      if (result.status === 200) {
//        localStorage.setItem('nick', result.data[1])
//        localStorage.setItem('email', result.data[3])
//      }
//    }) 

const UserInfo = () => {
 useEffect(() => {
  getDataByToken("http://127.0.0.1:5000/@me").then(result => {
    if (result.status === 200) {
      localStorage.setItem('nick', result.data[1])
      localStorage.setItem('email', result.data[3])
    }
  })
 }, []);

...
}
...
export default UserInfo
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not really good at React (as you can see). Next time will check more info 'bout React functions before asking. Thank you very much!